# why .webp larger than .png?

Tags: android, webp

why **.webp** larger than **.png**?

I Used ABIC program to convert png -> webp. But some of files are larger than origin png files.

**.webp file**
[image: web file]

**origin png file**
[image: 2]]

And diff-res is here. 
[image: 3]]

Two problems:

1. Why png -> webp come larger?
2. I don't feel size saving while using webp pics. How can Android compression pic files to get a great effect?

Comment: How did you export the image? There's different quality settings that affect the file size.

Comment: https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/png-vs-webp/

Comment: I used 75 percent quality

Comment: Instead of using naive file formats, I'd stick with the officially supported ones.

Answer (score 5):

Use `-near_lossless 40` on cwebp for best results with PNGs.

Answer (score 1):

From my tests Webp only produces good results when compared to JPG.
Against PNG however, it needs twice the filesize to produce a lossless copy.
If you really care about pixel perfect (pixel art and the likes) Webp is not a good format at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the resulting image can be bigger. It is just a limitation of the WebP algorithm. Especially when the original file is already optimized. Google explains it [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq#can_a_webp_image_grow_larger_than_its_source_image)

> usually when converting from a lossy format to WebP lossless or vice versa. This is mainly due to the colorspace difference (YUV420 vs ARGB) and the conversion between these.